# Possible to detect if the button Sender was from a Touch Up Inside vs. a Touch Up Outside?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a button that I would like both its Touch Up Inside and Touch Up Outside actions to all the same method. I then want the method to sort out which event happened, something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonMethod:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (event == UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
    NSLog(@"Touch up inside!");

if (event == UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)
    NSLog(@"Touch up outside!");   
}
}
```

This doesn't seem to work because the touch events seem to inherit from UIControl which isn't in the same universe as UIEvent. Is there any way to tell in my method which action caused the method to be called?

Comment: Why have your touch up inside and touch up outside methods wired to the same action?

Comment: Then why don't you separate it out with two methods.

Comment: Because the two methods will do almost the exact same thing except the Touch Up Outside will do one more thing. If it's possible to detect what type of action called the method I'd prefer to do that and have one less method and less code.

Answer (score 3):

Split it into two methods, if for some reason you want your logic in just one just pass along the message.

```
- (IBAction)buttonMethod:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event controlEvent:(UIControlEvents)event {
    if (event == UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
        NSLog(@"Touch up inside!");

    if (event == UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)
        NSLog(@"Touch up outside!");   
}

- (IBAction)buttonUpInside:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self buttonMethod:sender forEvent:event controlEvent:UIControlTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)buttonUpOutside:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self buttonMethod:sender forEvent:event controlEvent:UIControlTouchUpOutside];
}
```

Comment: The whole point is I want to avoid adding extraneous methods and code if I don't have to. I get that I can have different methods but I'm trying to avoid it. If it is impossible to detect the type of button event then I will just close this question.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. There is (deliberately) no way to get the type of event from action method.

Comment: Warning: Redefinition of method parameter 'event'. Error: Extraneous closing brace ('}').